# Question about upper central series of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

I am trying to figure out nilpotent groups, and it says that a group $G$ is nilpotent if there is a non-negative integers $c$ such that $Z^c(G) = G$.

Now an upper central series is something like $Z^0(G) \leq Z^1(G) \leq Z^2(G) \leq \ldots$ where $Z^0(G) = 1$ and $Z^1(G) = Z(G)$. But it doesn't say what $Z^2(G)$ is, it just says that $Z^2(G) / Z^1(G) = Z(G / Z^1 G)$. Since $G / Z^1(G)$ is a group whose elements are sets, $Z^2(G) / Z^1(G)$ will also be a set whose elements are sets. How do you solve for $Z^2(G)$, if you want to check if $Z^2(G) = G$?

Comment: But you have exactly what $Z_2(G)$ is! It is uniquely defined by the property $Z_2(G)/Z(G) = G/Z(G)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt But $Z_2(G)$ should be a set with elements of $G$. $Z_2(G)/Z(G)$ is a set with elements that are sets (and those sets contain elements of $G$). So $Z_2(G)$ can't be equal to $Z_2(G)/Z(G)$. Maybe I don't understand what "uniquely defined" means (I thought it means "equal to").

Comment: I didn't say that $Z_2(G)$ was equal to $Z_2(G)/Z(G)$. I said $Z_2(G)/Z(G) = Z(G/Z(G))$ (which is what you wrote anyway! And that does define $Z_2(G)$. I guess you want a definition that looks like $Z_2(G) = \{ g \in G \mid {\rm some\ property\ of}\ g \}$. You can do that yourself!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the group $Z(G/Z(G))$. Then it is a subgroup of the factor group $G/Z(G)$, say $H/Z(G)$. Therefore $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $Z(G)$. Now we write $H = Z_2(G)$. For example, consider the dihedral group $G = D_8$. You can check that $|Z(G)|=2$. Now $G/Z(G)$ is a group of order $4$ and in particular is abelian. Therefore $$G/Z(G) = Z(G/Z(G)) = Z_2(G) /Z(G).$$ Hence we have $G = Z_2(G)$ and $G$ is of class 2.

Comment: How do you know $G/Z(G)$ is an abelian group of order $4$?

Comment: Every group of order $p^2$ where $p$ is a prime number is abelian.

Comment: Sorry, I meant how do you know it is a group of order $4$ in the first place

Comment: In this example $|G| =8$ and $|Z(G)|=2$. So $G/Z(G)$ is of order $4$.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand that part. But in our definition, it says $G$ is nilpotent with nilpotency degree of $2$ if $Z_2(G) = G$. I don't really see how do you got from $G/Z(G) = Z_2(G)/Z(G)$ to $G = Z_2(G)$, but in practice do we just check every $Z_c(G)/Z(G)$ until we find one that is equal to $G/(Z)G$?

Comment: You should prove in general that, if $H/N = L/N$  then $H = L$.

Answer (score 0):

Read this link it may help you
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_series